# PHP 7.3 Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, warnings

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

```
$tags=locchuoi($request,"<span class='SeoH1'>",'</span>');
for($ll=1;$ll<count($tags)+1;$ll++)
{
    $tag_link =   $tag_link.$tags[$ll].",";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tags=locchuoi($request,"<span class='SeoH1'>",'</span>');
for($ll=1;$ll<(!empty($tags) ? count($tags)+1 : 0);$ll++)
{
   $tag_link =   $tag_link.$tags[$ll].",";
}
```

Try this code, I just add some condition inside the for() , when the $tags varible is empty return 0 , if not return count($tags)+1 .

Answer (score 4):

simple replace `Count` with `!empty` your problem is solved

```html
$tags=locchuoi($request,"<span class='SeoH1'>",'</span>');
for($ll=1;$ll<=(!empty($tags) ? count($tags) : 0);$ll++)
{
    $tag_link =   $tag_link.$tags[$ll].",";
}
```

Comment: when `!empty($tags)` is true , just return 1 , not return array or object length

Comment: its like my answer -_- , but its okay

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($tags);
```

use this and check the output of tags. 
it might be null, so you are getting like this.check

```
 `locchuoi($request,"<span class='SeoH1'>",'</span>');`
```

this function is returning the exact output which you need.